# Is it possible to pull data from a json file stored in Azure DevOps repository into an excel table

Tags: excel, git, azure-devops

We have a number of json files that sit in origin/master branch that get updated regularly, I would like to be able to query a particular set of files and import the json data into an excel spreadsheet.

Is this even possible to do, I have tried to Get Data -> From Web and pass in the url like so: https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_git/yyy?path=/file.json but this isn't the direct file itself so fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no direct way to import Json file in Azure DevOps repo into Excel. It's suggested that you could run `git clone` to clone your repo to your local machine. Then open the Json files in Excel from **Get Data** -> **From File**  -> **From JSON**. You can run `git pull` in your local repo to get the latest version before viewing in Excel.

---

Updated

As a workaround, you can copy your target Json files in your Azure DevOps repo into [Azure Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-overview) via the pipeline automatically. Then the users can view the Json files in Excel via the file URL.

1. Create a pipeline and use [AzureFileCopy@5 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-file-copy-v5?view=azure-pipelines) to copy Json files into Azure Storage. You can choose to synchronize Json files to the storage account every time there are changes or set a specific time through [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) to synchronize.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@5
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/JsonFiles/*'
    azureSubscription: '{The ARM service connection}'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: '{Your storage account name}'
    ContainerName: '{Your container name}'
```

2. Go to your storage account -> click Containers -> find and click your target container -> click your Json file. Then you can get the url of the file.
   [image]
3. Go to your Excel -> Data -> From Web -> Input the url of the file.
   [image]

Comment: I thought that may be the case, unfortunately we want to give access to this data to users that do not have the permissions or even skills the access the git repo. The excel file will be a shared file within sharepoint

Comment: As a workaround, you can copy your target Json files in your Azure DevOps repo into Azure Storage via the pipeline automatically. Then the users can view the Json files in Excel via the file URL. I have updated the steps in the above answer.